# Como puedo sumar dos float y obtener un entero?

Tags: java

Hola chicos como puedo obtener un entero sumando dos float ejemplo

```
float a = 2.3f;
float b = 1.9f;



a= (int) Math.round(2.3);
b=(int) Math.round(1.9);
```

utilize este pero de salida me da 4.0

Y que la salida sea 4 en vez de 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java es un lenguaje tipado. El tipo de las variables se indica al declararlas, y **no cambia** durante toda la vida de estas.

Has declarado las variables como `float`, por lo tanto, **siempre van a contener números en coma flantante**.

Simplemente, declara y utiliza 2 variables nuevas:

```
float a = 2.3f;
float b = 1.9f;
int ia = (int) Math.round(2.3);
int ib =(int) Math.round(1.9);
```